# Implement a random math operation (+, -, or *)

Tags: python, variables, math, random

My Python code needs to be able to randomly generate a number between 1 and 3 to determine what function to perform (addition, multiplication or subtraction). That works fine. I randomly generate two numbers and need to get this random function. So it would be like a basic maths sum like 3 + 6 = 9. The 3 would be stored as number1 (and randomly generated). The + would be stored as function and would also be randomly generated. The 6 would be stored as number2 and also randomly generated.

The problem I am having is combining all the variables together and getting it to work out the maths.

So I could do the following: **(the numbers entered would have been randomly generated)**

```
number1 = 3
number2 = 8
function = 3 (for the purposes of this: addition)

function then is changed to "+"
```

I am left doing this:

```
answer = number1, function, number2
```

Which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: This must be a common homework or workbook problem, as a google search revealed other questions on SO this month:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28000403/randomly-generating-math-questions  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755270/python-quiz-isnt-outputting-the-correct-code-at-times  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77299/math-equation-generator-program

Comment: Nobody cares about poor division?  Don't use "math" - this is more like "early grammar school integer arithmetic".  Remove that math tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the binary operator functions defined in the `operator` module.  The functions `operator.add()`, `operator.sub()` and `operator.mul()` can all be called with two arguments to perform the operation their name suggests.

To select one of the three functions at random, you can simply put them in a list and then use `random.choice()`:

```
operators = [operator.add, operator.sub, operator.mul]
random_operator = random.choice(operators)
```

The random operator can be applied to your numbers like this:

```
result = random_operator(number1, number2)
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to use a function! The relevant functions for `+`, `-`, and `*` already exist as `operator.add`, `operator.sub`, and `operator.mul`.

```
import operator
import random

op_mappings = {"+":operator.add,
               "-":operator.sub,
               "*":operator.mul}

op = random.choice(["+", "-", "/"])
# this is better than mapping them to numbers, since it's
# immediately obvious to anyone reading your code what's going on

number1 = random.randint(1,20)
number2 = random.randint(1,20)

answer = op_mappings[op](number1, number2)
```

The operator functions work just like a normal expression, that is to say:

```
operator.add(x,y) == x + y
# et. al
```

So you're able to use them as objects in a dictionary. If you haven't used a dictionary before, now's a great time to learn! They're incredibly useful as hashmaps like I did above.

Comment: You could even just do `op = random.choice([operator.add,...])`.

Comment: @Kevin yeah I'd originally tried to save his `randint(1,3)` map to the operators, but it was too ugly to live. This was my compromise

Answer (score 1):

```
number1 = randint(1,20)
number2 = randint(1,20)

if function == 1:
    answer = number1 + number2
elif function == 2:
    answer = number1 - number2
elif function == 3:
    answer = number1 * number2
```

You don't have to over think it.

Comment: Less robust than the `operator` solutions but for this simple case may well be the preferred answer

Answer (score 1):

Beside using operator module. You could evaluate a string into code.

ex:

```
import random

number1 = random.randint(1,9)
operator = random.choice(r"+-/*")
number2 = random.randint(1,9)

result = eval( str(number1) + operator + str(number2))
print(number1,operator,number2,"=",result)
```

Outputs:

```
8 * 4 = 32
```

- Note that `eval` should NOT be used with untrusted inputs, like those coming from `input`, or any coming from a user interaction. Because it essentially runs the code inside it, if any malicious code is inside, IT WILL EXECUTE IT.